# Drag-and-drop ES6 imports in Visual Studio for TypeScript

Tags: module, typescript, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

Currently in Web-Essentials (for Visual Studio 2015), if a `.ts` file from the Solution Explorer is dragged and dropped into an open `.ts` file, a reference path is automatically inserted at the top:

```
/// <reference path="../playback/key.ts" />
```

This is fine when a project is being developed using internal modules (namespaces), but is virtually useless when going external. How could I make it so that an [ES6 import statement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#es6-modules) is generated instead? That would be awesome. Such as:

```
import {} from "../playback/key";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out what we are seeing is a built-in feature of Web-Essentials. I've filed a [feature-request](https://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/13442706-generate-es6-import-statements-for-typescript-modu) to get this available, hopefully in the near future.

---

In the meantime, the following [Visual Commander](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d) automation snippet can replace all references to ES6 imports:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    // Called by Visual Commander extension.
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        TextDocument doc = (TextDocument)(DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument"));
        var p = doc.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint();
        string s = p.GetText(doc.EndPoint);

        p.ReplaceText(doc.EndPoint, this.ReplaceReferences(s), (int)vsEPReplaceTextOptions.vsEPReplaceTextKeepMarkers);
    }

    // Converts "reference" syntax to "ES6 import" syntax.
    private string ReplaceReferences(string text)
    {
        string pattern = "\\/\\/\\/ *<reference *path *= *\"([^\"]*)(?:\\.ts)\" *\\/>";

        var regex = new Regex(pattern);
        var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

        return Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "import {} from \"./$1\";");
    }
}
```

The regex used to perform this replace is (without the double backslashes, more readable):

```
\/\/\/ *<reference *path *= *"([^"]*)(?:\.ts)" *\/>
```

This snippet will effectively convert all reference comments to ES6 imports in the currently active document, *very* useful.

---

**Known issues:**

- a comment containing a `reference` tag is not recognized by Visual Studio if it is preceded by other text in the corresponding line, but it is still replaced by this snippet
- additional text after a `reference` tag is valid, but after replace will cause syntax errors, since it is no longer a comment.

*(Neither of these issues are relevant if the snippet is used on reference tags generated by Web-Essentials when a `.ts` file is drag-and-dropped.)*